# How to embed SVG with Path into Html taken from a src?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I have an svg uploaded to my website and I want to embed it into my html so that it can have the structure of svg and path:

```
<svg>
    <path id="svgPath"/>
</svg>
```

I managed to do it with image

```
<svg width="1920" height"720">
  <image id="imgId" xlink:href="srclink" width="1920" height="720" />
</svg>
```

And when I query that image, I don't have the same methods that I have as for a `path` element. For example, I don't have the `.getTotalLength()`

```
const path = document.querySelector("#pathId");
path.getTotalLength(); // will work

const img = document.querySelector("#imgId");
img.getTotallength(); // does not work
```

I can insert it with Javascript too, if there is a way to do that while loading it from the `srclink`.

I `need` to be able to access the path as the rest of my code is dependent on that.

Answer (score 0):

If it is an external `*.svg` file, A native Web Component `<load-file>` can *fetch* it and inject it in the DOM; either in shadowDOM or replacing the `<load-file>` Element, thus becoming part of the DOM you can access and style with CSS.

```js
customElements.define("load-file", class extends HTMLElement {

  // declare default connectedCallback as sync so await can be used
  async connectedCallback(
    // call connectedCallback with parameter to *replace* SVG (of <load-file> persists)
    src = this.getAttribute("src"),
    // attach a shadowRoot if none exists (prevents displaying error when moving Nodes)
    shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot || this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
  ) {
      // load SVG file from src="" async, parse to text, add to shadowRoot.innerHTML
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = await (await fetch(src)).text()

    // append optional <tag [shadowRoot]> Elements from inside <load-svg> after parsed <svg>
    shadowRoot.append(...this.querySelectorAll("[shadowRoot]"))

    // if "replaceWith" attribute 
    // then replace <load-svg> with loaded content <load-svg>
    // childNodes instead of children to include #textNodes also
    this.hasAttribute("replaceWith") && this.replaceWith(...shadowRoot.childNodes)
  }
})
```

Full explanation in Dev.To post: [〈load-file〉Web Component, add external content to the DOM](https://dev.to/dannyengelman/load-file-web-component-add-external-content-to-the-dom-1nd)